# How to pass many queue id to a thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a problem with this program in C. In a nutshell I have to send the data created by a sensor, through an aggregator. The aggregator, through a writer thread, read the value generated by the sensor to three different queues through three reader threads (thread_lettore) only that when I create the threads, all three connect to the last queue created. I would like have each thread with its own queue. Passing the message queue id of the sensor is easy because is only one message queue but how can I pass a different message queue id to each thread?

I found the error in this `for` cycle but I can't resolve it. It generates the correct queues but when I pass the arguments to the `pthread_create`, it pass only the last queue created.

```
 MonitorLS * m = (MonitorLS*) malloc(sizeof(MonitorLS));

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
            m->id_coda_c = id_code_collettori[i];
            pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, thread_lettore, (void*)m);
        }
```

This is the structure in the header file:

```
typedef struct {

    int variabile;

    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cv_lett;
    pthread_cond_t cv_scritt;

    int num_scrittori;
    int num_lettori;
    int id_coda_s;
    int id_coda_c;

} MonitorLS;
```

This is how I create three different message queues in the main file:

```
char chiave = 'a';
int id_code_collettori[3];
for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
   key_t key_c = ftok (".", chiave);
   id_code_collettori[i] = msgget(key_c, IPC_CREAT|0644);
   chiave = chiave + 1;
}
```

This is a homework exercise that my university professor assigned to me. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You are sending the same pointer to every thread. That pointer is the address of some bit of memory. In that memory you are writing all the queue IDs. When you write data in memory, it replaces the previous data at the same address.

Comment: I know, I searched various solutions on google but I can't reach a solution to this problem

Comment: Do you understand the problem?

Comment: @user253751 yes but I try many ways to resolve but I couldn't solve it

Comment: can you explain what causes the problem in your own words?

Comment: The problem is caused because I can't pass the queue id to `pthread_create`, I have to pass a different message queue to each different threads.

Comment: And can you explain why your program is not doing that?

Comment: Because when I pass `m->id_coda_c` to `pthread_create` instead of passing a different id each time, it pass the same queue id

Comment: But you don't pass `m->id_coda_c` to `pthread_create`

Comment: What do you mean? Please, can you help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: I mean you don't pass `m->id_coda_c` to `pthread_create`. It doesn't say `pthread_create(m->id_coda_c)`. And for a problem this simple and for homework, I would like to help you understand it, by yourself, not just tell you the answer.

Comment: I know you want to help me understand the problem but I have been trying for days to do this homework and I have not been able to solve it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you only allocate one MonitorLS struct.
You put the first queue ID in the struct. You start the first thread. You put the second queue ID in the struct. You start the second thread. You put the third queue ID in the struct. You start the third thread.

... a few microseconds later, the first thread starts up and looks at the struct and gets the queue ID (which is the **third** one because that's what you put there).
... a few microseconds later, the second thread starts up and looks at the struct and gets the queue ID (which is the **third** one because that's what you put there).
... a few microseconds later, the third thread starts up and looks at the struct and gets the queue ID (which is the **third** one because that's what you put there).

So, you need to use three different variables to store the three different queue IDs, instead of using one variable three times. You could allocate three different MonitorLS structs, one per thread. In fact, that is basically your only option. I see that MonitorLS has other stuff in it, though, so you might want to make *another* struct (let's call it ThreadInfo), that has a pointer to your MonitorLS struct (same pointer in every ThreadInfo) and a queue ID (different in every ThreadInfo).